# What are these white and thick things in my egg?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I bought a carton of eggs 6 days ago, and all the eggs have these white and thick spots in them. Not sure how to describe it. Does it mean the eggs went bad?

[image]

Did they go bad? The eggs are suppose to be good till April 12th.

[image]

Comment: Are you describing the chalaza? See this: http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/birds/info/chicken/egg.shtml   They look normal to me.

Comment: @moscafj Right, it seems I am seeing the chalazae. It is incredible I had never seen it before in other eggs. This is the first time I buy this brand of eggs. Thanks!

Comment: Beto, welcome to Seasoned Advice! Let me encourage you to take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: If the whites are holding up as well, (not runny) these are both indications that the eggs are fresher than the ones you're used to.